#  Display as squares in my Silverlight Dropdown box

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, unicode

I'm working on getting my website GB18030 certified and part of the characters i need to support are the ones in the title.

It works everywhere besides in silverlight.
I've scoured the web to find out why and didn't really figure out anything.
I then had an epiphany and thought maybe it's the font.

So i went into notepad (2008 R2 server box). and put in the characters using arial.
And behold. the squares appeared.

I then swapped to Lucinda Sans Unicode. And tada! they were displaying properly.
I swapped from Arial to Lucinda Sans Unicode in my Silverlight. but alas, they remain squares.

Does anyone have a clue what my issue might be?
I'm storing the values using UTF8 in my code behind the string comes across correct.

Comment: U+E844 is in the *private use* area, only the SimSun font family has the proper glyphs.  Be sure to test this on a machine that's itself GB18030 compatible, use the Chinese language version of Windows.  Font fall back won't work correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what i had to do was Add the SimSun.ttc to my project and use that as the display font.
For some reason all the other fonts don't fall back to SimSun.

If someone can explain to me why the browser(HTML) does display correctly with any font. and Silverlight doesn't i think i could learn alot.

Thanks for the effort!